# How to get a userId of particular site users in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to get a userId of particular site users in SharePoint 2013.

My REST endpoint to get site users is,

```
http://site url/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='i:0#.w|domain\Id'
```

But I am getting an error "The query string "loginName" is missing or invalid."

when I send only  `http://site url/_api/web/siteusers, am able to fetch all the records.`

Record format

```
<entry>
        <id>..</id>
        <category term="SP.User" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/GetUserById(118)" />
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Groups" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Groups" href="Web/GetUserById(118)/Groups" />
        <title />
        <updated>2016-05-18T13:26:01Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">118</d:Id>
                 .
                 .
                <d:LoginName>i:0#.w|tes\112533</d:LoginName>
                <d:Title>112533</d:Title>
                 .
                 .

            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    .
    .
    .
```

How to get individual user id Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your user name. So instead of i:0#.w|tes\112533 you need to put

```
_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v=%27i%3A0%23.W%7Ctes%5C112533%27
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code can be included on your page to fetch the `UserId` of a given Site User.

```
//
// Include JQuery reference
// ... script continues ...

        /// username should be passed as 'domain\username'
        function GetUserId(userName) {
            /// change this prefix according to the environment. 
            /// In below sample, windows authentication is considered.
            var prefix = "i:0#.w|";
            /// get the site url
            var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
            /// add prefix, this needs to be changed based on scenario
            var accountName = prefix + userName;

            /// make an ajax call to get the site user
            $.ajax({
                url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='" + 
                    encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    ///popup user id received from site users.
                    alert("Received UserId" + data.d.Id);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
        }
```

For SharePoint Online or on-premise forms authentication, use the below login name format:

```
i: 0#.f|membership|user@domain.com
```

For SharePoint 2013 on-premise Windows authentication, use the below login name format:

```
i: 0#.w|domain\user
```

For SharePoint 2013 on-premise SAML based authentication, use the below login name format:

```
?i: 05:t|adfs with roles|user@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this endpoint (SP2013 OnPrem):

```
_api/web/ensureUser('user@email.com')
```

This makes sure the user is created on the site and returns the principal ID of the user. I suspect you knows the email of the user if you know their domain login.